# Removing Duplicate Sets of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, sql-delete

### Data

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tbl_LinkedInvoices(
    InvoiceNbr              varchar(50)
,   AssociatedInvoiceNbr    varchar(50)
,   RowNbr                  int
,   AssociatedRowNbr        int
)
INSERT INTO #tbl_LinkedInvoices(
        InvoiceNbr, AssociatedInvoiceNbr, RowNbr, AssociatedRowNbr)
VALUES 
    ('A0001', 'A1001', 1, 4),
    ('A0002', 'A2002', 2, 5),
    ('A0002', 'A3002', 3, 6),
    ('A1001', 'A0001', 4, 1),
    ('A2002', 'A0002', 5, 2),
    ('A3002', 'A0002', 6, 3)

    SELECT * FROM #tbl_LinkedInvoices
```

### Challenge/Goal

`tbl_LinkedInvoices` is meant to identify the `AssociatedInvoiceNbrs` `b` an `InvoiceNbr` `a` is linked to. As such, a set can appear multiple times in the table since `(a, b) = (b,a)`. To address these reappearances `RowNbr` and `AssociatedRowNbr` fields are added to give grouped sequences.

With the identified duplicate rows, remove duplicate row, preserving a single unique record in the table. Current script yields error, expect there might be a better way to write the query.

### Script

Use a counter to check if the duplicate row still exists, if it does delete that row, till `FALSE`.

```sql
DECLARE @RowCounter int
DECLARE @RemoveRow int
SET @RowCounter = 1



IF EXISTS (SELECT 
              RowNbr
           FROM #tbl_LinkedInvoices WHERE RowNbr = (SELECT AssociatedRowNbr FROM #tbl_LinkedInvoices)
)
BEGIN
   SET @RemoveRow = (SELECT RowNbr FROM #tbl_LinkedINvoices
                     WHERE RowNbr = (
                            SELECT AssociatedRowNbr FROM #tbl_LinkedInvoices WHERE RowNbr =@RowCounter ))
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM #tbl_LinkedInvoices
        WHERE
        RowNbr = @RemoveRow
    END
    BEGIN
        SET @RowCounter = @RowCounter + 1
    END
END
```

### Error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 212
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Comment: Isn't the error clear?  Use `in` instead of `=`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - `IN` returns all or nothing since existence of values is in both columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you can perform the deletion of "mirror" records in a single statement, without using the additional computed columns:

```
delete t
from #tbl_LinkedInvoices t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from #tbl_LinkedInvoices t1 
    where 
        t1.AssociatedInvoiceNbr = t.InvoiceNbr
        and t1.InvoiceNbr = t.AssociatedInvoiceNbr
        and t1.AssociatedInvoiceNbr > t.AssociatedInvoiceNbr
)
```

This removes mirror records while retaining the one whose `InvoiceNbr` is smaller than `AssociatedInvoiceNbr`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=766b7dc8b0ffc1c83f1cdcb2cadc3a3c)** with your sample data.

After the `delete` statement is executed, the content of the table is:

```
InvoiceNbr | AssociatedInvoiceNbr | RowNbr | AssociatedRowNbr
:--------- | :------------------- | -----: | ---------------:
A0001      | A1001                |      1 |                4
A0002      | A2002                |      2 |                5
A0002      | A3002                |      3 |                6
```

Comment: This ended up working. Smart usage of `EXISTS` and utilizing the last comparison operator to mathematically give precedence in case of duplicates. Thank you!